# php voting of five candidates and printing sum of votes

Tags: php, html, arrays

Can anyone recommend me a good function or suggest how to do the adding one extra point to the candidate with more votes? The summing part seems to work fine but when echoing the final result I want it to include one extra point. Thank you! **Task:**

Your task is to write an election application that contains five candidates, of which only one can be voted at a time. Save the casted votes to the file results.txt. There are five rows in this file. Each row has the candidate's election number (1-5) and received votes. The election number and received votes are separated with a | character. Therefore the file structure looks like this:

```
1|2
2|6
3|8
4|3
5|10
```

Your task is to write a PHP script that changes results.txt after voting so that the voted candidate receives one extra vote. The program should print the total amount of cast votes including the latest vote. The used form looks like this:

```
<form action="voting.php" method="get">

Choose your candidate:

<select name="candidate">

<option value=1 selected>1</option>        

<option value=2>2</option>

<option value=3>3</option>

<option value=4>4</option>

<option value=5>5</option>

</select>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">                  

</form>

 
Example output
 

Total votes casted: 12 votes.
```

**Code:**

```
 <?php
$inputs = file('results.txt');
$sum = 0 ;
$res = array();

foreach ($inputs as $line) {
  $var = explode('|', $line);
  $res[$var[0]] = $var[1];
  $add= $add +  $var[1];
}
$fin=array();
$maxVotes=max($res);
foreach ($res as $candidate => $voteCount) {
  if ($voteCount == $maxVotes) {
  $fin=$candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate];
    $res[$candidate]++;
    
  }
}
$final = implode("\n", $fin);
$fp = fopen('results.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $final);
fclose($fp);
echo "Total votes casted: ",$add+1," votes.";
$file = 'results.txt';
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: No, it is a self study trying to improve my knowledge in php. I am new to php. I have tried all my best spent hours to print the extra one point but couldn't come up with a good function or way.

Comment: ok, I trust you, please find my answer below

Comment: You never need to declare the `value` of an option tag if it is identical to the option's text.  If you want the first option to be selected, you don't need to declare `selected` because the first is selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an array while reading the file:

```
$res = array();

foreach ($inputs as $line) {
  $var = explode('|', $line);
  $res[$var[0]] = $var[1];
}
```

Now the array contains candidate id as key and vote count as value. So, for example vote count for candidate 4 is `$res[4]`.

You can find max votes by `max($res)`.

The candidate(s) with most votes can be found with another loop:
(assuming `max($res)` is stored in a variable named `$maxVotes`.

```
foreach ($res as $candidate => $voteCount) {
  if ($voteCount == $maxVotes) {
    $res[$candidate]++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, have you tried it? it is not printing the extra point for me?

Comment: Not needed to try. I did not mean to provide you a complete code. You can see in the second loop I am incrementing vote count for candidates with max votes. At the end of second loop you can `print_r($res);` to see counts.

Comment: To my understanding I thought that was it. So can you tell me what is missing I mean don't write the code for me just tell me in words. And do you know a good source which I can read from?

Comment: I am not sure I got you right but I will try to describe my method. When you construct an array with indices as candidate ids, you can easily access votes of candidates (as we did like `$res[$candidate]`). Such arrays are useful than arrays with indices starting at `0` in similar cases. That was the main idea in my method. If you learn array operations, you will be much more comfortable with PHP. I suggest you spend some time on that. Most people learn from the origin: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Ok I understand what you did in both codes, when I tried to write the result it is giving me the sum of all votes. How do we write the results back to results.txt including the final added vote for $res[$candidate] which got the max vote?

Comment: You can construct another array holding the value for a single row. In the second foreach block (after if block) you can put `$candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate]` in an array, then after foreach block `implode` this array with newlines ("\n") and write to the file

Comment: Hi, I have tried to add the missing codes as you suggested, but when I test it it says "Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed" I am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

While not the most basic technique, I don't want to perform explosions within nested loops to completely parse the file data, only to increment a single value.

Instead, I would find the single line in the file that starts with the submitted candidate id, then isolate its current vote tally, then increment that.

To find the total of all votes, isolate the number that immediately follows the pipes in the file.

To overwrite the file with the new data, call `file_put_contents()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UosfQ))

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents('results.txt');
/*$fileContents = <<<TEXT
1|2
2|6
3|8
4|3
5|10
TEXT;*/

// let's assume:    $_GET['candidate'] = '4';
if (isset($_GET['candidate'])) {
    $fileContents = preg_replace_callback(
        '~^' . (int)$_GET['candidate'] . '\|\K\d+~m',
        function($m) {
            return ++$m[0];
        },
        $fileContents,
        1                   // only logically possible to make one replacement
    );
    echo "New total: " . array_sum(preg_match_all('~\|\K\d+~', $fileContents, $m) ? $m[0] : []);
    file_put_contents('results.txt', $fileContents);
}
```

Output from demonstration:

```
New total: 30
---
1|2
2|6
3|8
4|4
5|10
```

Pro Tip: When a form will submit data that will lead to a data being saved/written on the server/database, it is best practice to submit with `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.