# Voting of five candidates and print out sum PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

Your task is to write an election application that contains five candidates, of which only one can be voted at a time. Save the casted votes to the file results.txt. There are five rows in this file. Each row has the candidate's election number (1-5) and received votes. The election number and received votes are separated with a | character. Therefore the file structure looks like this:

```
1|2
2|6
3|8
4|3
5|10
```

Your task is to write a PHP script that changes results.txt after voting so that the voted candidate receives one extra vote. The program should print the total amount of cast votes including the latest vote. The used form looks like this:

```
 <form action="voting.php" method="get">

 Choose your candidate:

 <select name="candidate">

 <option value=1 selected>1</option>        

 <option value=2>2</option>

 <option value=3>3</option>

 <option value=4>4</option>

 <option value=5>5</option>

 </select>

 <br>

 <input type="submit" value="Send">                  

 </form>
```

Example output

```
 Total votes: 15786.
```

I manage to get this far:

```
  <?php
$inputs = file('results.txt');

foreach ($inputs as $line) {
  $var = explode('|', $line);
  $res[$var[0]] = $var[1];
  $add= $add +  $var[1];
}

$fin=array();
$maxVotes=max($res);
foreach ($res as $candidate => $voteCount) {
  if ($voteCount == $maxVotes) {
    $fin=$candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate];
    $res[$candidate]++;
  }
}

$final = implode("\n", $fin);

$fp = fopen('results.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $final);
fclose($fp);
echo "Total votes: ",$add+1,".";
$file = 'results.txt';
readfile($file);

?>
```

My result shows me:

```
implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
Total votes: 30.
```

Comment: I feel like I already (recently) answered this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054407/2943403  Where are people copying this webform from? Some bad tutorial?  There is no benefit in writing the `value` in the `<option>` if it is exactly the same as the `<option>`'s text.  It is not necessary to specify `selected` if you are selecting the first `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you start as `$fin=array();`. But later inside the loop, you convert/replace `$fin` as a string.

`$fin=$candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate];`

So this means at the point `$fin` is going inside the `implode` method, it is a string, not an array.

```
$final = implode("\n", $fin);
```

[Read about PHP implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Sorry, I fix the code on my IDE but forgot to fix it in the post. But it still gives the same error.

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. Hope it helps.